usepackage xr not working despite aux files generating fine
my document class is
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,prl,
]{revtex4-2}

There is a MAIN.tex and a SuppInfo.tex in the overleaf project, and i want to cross reference figures from each .tex file in the other.  I also have the file called latexmkrc in the project, that I copied **directly from here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf
I have tried both
\usepackage{xr}

and
\usepackage{xr-hyper}

along with calling
\externaldocument{MAIN}

in the SuppInfo.tex file and
\externaldocument{SuppInfo}

in the MAIN.tex file.
The latexmkrc is working fine in that the aux files are generating, and they are not empty; they have all the cross referencing labels that I want in there.  So that part looks fine. But still, using \ref in one of the tex files and a label from the other file still leads to ?? in the compiled pdf.  Someone else on here said it only worked for them if they didn't use the \includegraphics command.  so i also tried commenting that out and still it doesn't work.
even the log files say it IS importing references from the other file, but then later down in the log file it says the references are undefined.
also simply recompiling a few times in a row doesn't help.
any suggestions?
thank you in advance!
EDITED: thank you for your comments; here is the entire code block of MAIN.tex, and below this follows the entire code block of SuppInfo.tex.  they have been greatly abbreviated -- each just has a single labeled figure that is referenced in the other file. I also removed all of the comments from the 'helper code' I had copy-pasted from https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf. these files both compile but the references to the other figure in the other file still appear as ??
MAIN.tex
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,prl,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xr}
\makeatletter

%begin helper code
\newcommand*{\addFileDependency}[1]{% argument=file name and extension
\typeout{(#1)}
\@addtofilelist{#1}
\IfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}
}\makeatother
\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[1]{%
\externaldocument{#1}%
\addFileDependency{#1.tex}%
\addFileDependency{#1.aux}%
} %end helper code
\externaldocument{SuppInfo}

\begin{document}

\preprint{APS/123-QED}


\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/Figure 3.eps}
\caption{\label{DefineWiggle} (a) shows the definition. The full distribution is shown in Figure \ref{SI-lengths}.}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}

SuppInfo.tex
\documentclass[
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{xr}
\makeatletter

%begin helper code
\newcommand*{\addFileDependency}[1]{% argument=file name and extension
\typeout{(#1)}
\@addtofilelist{#1}
\IfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}
}\makeatother
\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[1]{%
\externaldocument{#1}%
\addFileDependency{#1.tex}%
\addFileDependency{#1.aux}%
} %end helper code

\externaldocument{MAIN}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{SI figures/Final SI Figures/SI 7 - Lengths.eps}
\caption{\label{SI-lengths} Histogram obtained by the method described in Figure \ref{DefineWiggle}.}
\end{figure}
  
\end{document}

also here is the raw log from compiling MAIN.tex:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=xelatex 2023.8.28)  5 JUN 2024 14:12
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**MAIN.tex
(./MAIN.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-06-30>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/revtex4-2.cls
Document Class: revtex4-2 2022/06/05 4.2f (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for documentation)
 Copyright (c) 2019 American Physical Society.
 mailto:revtex@aps.org
 Licensed under the LPPL:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/lppl.txt
 Arthur Ogawa <arthur_ogawa at sbcglobal dot net>
 Based on work by David Carlisle <david at dcarlisle.demon.co.uk>
 Version (4.2d--4.2f): Modified by Mark Doyle and Phelype Oleinik
 .
ltxutil[2022/06/05 4.2f utilities package (portions licensed from W. E. Baxter web at superscript.com)]
LaTeX Info: Redefining \@centercr on input line 356.
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing broken LaTeX eqnarray on input line 417.
\eqncolsep=\skip48
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing hyperref-unfriendly LaTeX definition of \mpfootnote on input line 492.
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing broken LateX \@sect on input line 814.
\intertabularlinepenalty=\count181
\@tbpen=\count182
\@arstrutbox@hline=\box51
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing broken LaTeX \@xbitor on input line 1845.
Class revtex4-2 Info: Making \typeout \long on input line 2110.
ltxfront[2022/06/05 4.2f frontmatter package (AO,DPC,MD)]
\c@affil=\count183
\c@collab=\count184
\absbox=\box52
ltxgrid[2022/06/05 4.2f page grid package (portions licensed from W. E. Baxter web at superscript.com)]
\c@linecount=\count185
\output@latex=\toks17
\box@size@1=\box53
\box@size@2=\box54
\@protection@box=\box55
\@topmark@saved=\toks18
\footins@saved=\box56
\footins@recovered=\box57
\column@recovered=\box58
\pagesofar=\box59
\footsofar=\box60
\pagegrid@col=\count186
Class revtex4-2 Info: Overriding \@vspace, \@vspacer, \@no@pgbk, \@newline, and \\  on input line 5676.
\c@part=\count187
\c@section=\count188
\c@subsection=\count189
\c@subsubsection=\count190
\c@paragraph=\count191
\c@subparagraph=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip49
\belowcaptionskip=\skip50
\c@figure=\count193
\fbox@1=\box61
\c@table=\count194
\fbox@2=\box62
\c@video=\count195
\fbox@4=\box63
\@bibdataout=\write3
\widetext@top=\box64
\widetext@bot=\box65
Class revtex4-2 Info: Selecting society aps on input line 7669.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/aps4-2.rtx
File: aps4-2 2022/06/05 4.2f (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for documentation)
Class revtex4-2 Info: RevTeX society APS selected on input line 40.
)
Class revtex4-2 Info: Selecting journal prl on input line 7671.
Class revtex4-2 Info: APS journal PRL selected on input line 7672.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/aps10pt4-2.rtx
File: aps10pt4-2 2022/06/05 4.2f (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for documentation)
Class revtex4-2 Info: RevTeX pointsize 10pt selected on input line 39.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty
Package: textcase 2022/07/10 v1.03 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
Package textcase Info: Defining Legacy names on input line 20.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks19
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2023/05/13 v2.17o AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip51
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks20
\ex@=\dimen140
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \text on input line 28.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen141
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count196
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count197
\leftroot@=\count198
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 410.
\classnum@=\count199
\DOTSCASE@=\count266
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box66
\strutbox@=\box67
LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 722.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 724.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 725.
\big@size=\dimen142
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count267
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 905.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 910.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 940.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 970.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 971.
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count268
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count269
\dspbrk@lvl=\count270
\tag@help=\toks21
\row@=\count271
\column@=\count272
\maxfields@=\count273
\andhelp@=\toks22
\eqnshift@=\dimen143
\alignsep@=\dimen144
\tagshift@=\dimen145
\tagwidth@=\dimen146
\totwidth@=\dimen147
\lineht@=\dimen148
\@envbody=\toks23
\multlinegap=\skip52
\multlinetaggap=\skip53
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks24
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2953.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip17
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip54
\bibsep=\skip55
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count274
)
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing natbib's \BibitemShut on input line 7676.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/revsymb4-2.sty
Package: revsymb4-2 2022/06/05 4.2f (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for documentation)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frak on input line 104.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bbb on input line 120.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \REV@mathfrak on input line 128.
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks25
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 107.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2022/09/22 v5.0n Graphics/color driver for xetex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen149
\Gin@req@width=\dimen150
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/dcolumn.sty
Package: dcolumn 2014/10/28 v1.06 decimal alignment package (DPC)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2022/09/04 v2.5g Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen151
\ar@mcellbox=\box68
\extrarowheight=\dimen152
\NC@list=\toks26
\extratabsurround=\skip56
\backup@length=\skip57
\ar@cellbox=\box69
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/bm.sty
Package: bm 2022/01/05 v1.2f Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
\symboldoperators=\mathgroup6
\symboldletters=\mathgroup7
\symboldsymbols=\mathgroup8
Package bm Info: No bold for \OMX/cmex/m/n, using \pmb.
Package bm Info: No bold for \U/msa/m/n, using \pmb.
Package bm Info: No bold for \U/msb/m/n, using \pmb.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 149.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bm on input line 219.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xr.sty
Package: xr 2020-05-10 v5.06 eXternal References (DPC)
)
Package xr Info: IMPORTING LABELS FROM SuppInfo.aux on input line 24.
Class revtex4-2 Info: Unrecognized array package. Please update this document class! (Proceeding with fingers crossed.) on input line 26.
Class revtex4-2 Info: cite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 26.
Class revtex4-2 Info: mcite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 26.
Class revtex4-2 Info: multicol was not loaded (OK!) on input line 26.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2023-04-19 L3 backend support: XeTeX
\g__graphics_track_int=\count275
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box70
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count276
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count277
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count278
) (./output.aux)
\openout1 = `output.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 26.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
\openout3 = `outputNotes.bib'.

Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 32 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 32 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 32 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 32 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 32 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 32 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 32 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 32 replaced by U+FFFD.
File: figures/Figure 3.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<figures/Figure 3.eps>

LaTeX Warning: Reference `SI-lengths' on page 1 undefined on input line 33.

(./output.bbl) [1] (./output.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-06-30>
 ***********

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 4383 strings out of 475890
 61923 string characters out of 5778498
 1909875 words of memory out of 5000000
 25414 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558093 words of font info for 39 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 71i,5n,79p,222b,387s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

Output written on output.xdv (1 page, 1676 bytes).

and the raw log file from compiling SuppInfo.tex:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=xelatex 2023.8.28)  5 JUN 2024 14:14
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**SuppInfo.tex
(./SuppInfo.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-06-30>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/revtex4-2.cls
Document Class: revtex4-2 2022/06/05 4.2f (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for documentation)
 Copyright (c) 2019 American Physical Society.
 mailto:revtex@aps.org
 Licensed under the LPPL:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/lppl.txt
 Arthur Ogawa <arthur_ogawa at sbcglobal dot net>
 Based on work by David Carlisle <david at dcarlisle.demon.co.uk>
 Version (4.2d--4.2f): Modified by Mark Doyle and Phelype Oleinik
 .
ltxutil[2022/06/05 4.2f utilities package (portions licensed from W. E. Baxter web at superscript.com)]
LaTeX Info: Redefining \@centercr on input line 356.
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing broken LaTeX eqnarray on input line 417.
\eqncolsep=\skip48
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing hyperref-unfriendly LaTeX definition of \mpfootnote on input line 492.
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing broken LateX \@sect on input line 814.
\intertabularlinepenalty=\count181
\@tbpen=\count182
\@arstrutbox@hline=\box51
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing broken LaTeX \@xbitor on input line 1845.
Class revtex4-2 Info: Making \typeout \long on input line 2110.
ltxfront[2022/06/05 4.2f frontmatter package (AO,DPC,MD)]
\c@affil=\count183
\c@collab=\count184
\absbox=\box52
ltxgrid[2022/06/05 4.2f page grid package (portions licensed from W. E. Baxter web at superscript.com)]
\c@linecount=\count185
\output@latex=\toks17
\box@size@1=\box53
\box@size@2=\box54
\@protection@box=\box55
\@topmark@saved=\toks18
\footins@saved=\box56
\footins@recovered=\box57
\column@recovered=\box58
\pagesofar=\box59
\footsofar=\box60
\pagegrid@col=\count186
Class revtex4-2 Info: Overriding \@vspace, \@vspacer, \@no@pgbk, \@newline, and \\  on input line 5676.
\c@part=\count187
\c@section=\count188
\c@subsection=\count189
\c@subsubsection=\count190
\c@paragraph=\count191
\c@subparagraph=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip49
\belowcaptionskip=\skip50
\c@figure=\count193
\fbox@1=\box61
\c@table=\count194
\fbox@2=\box62
\c@video=\count195
\fbox@4=\box63
\@bibdataout=\write3
\widetext@top=\box64
\widetext@bot=\box65
Class revtex4-2 Info: Selecting society aps on input line 7669.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/aps4-2.rtx
File: aps4-2 2022/06/05 4.2f (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for documentation)
Class revtex4-2 Info: RevTeX society APS selected on input line 40.
)

Class revtex4-2 Warning: No journal specified, using default pra.

Class revtex4-2 Info: APS journal PRA selected on input line 7672.

Class revtex4-2 Warning: No type size specified, using default 10.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/aps10pt4-2.rtx
File: aps10pt4-2 2022/06/05 4.2f (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for documentation)
Class revtex4-2 Info: RevTeX pointsize 10pt selected on input line 39.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty
Package: textcase 2022/07/10 v1.03 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
Package textcase Info: Defining Legacy names on input line 20.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks19
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2023/05/13 v2.17o AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip51
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks20
\ex@=\dimen140
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \text on input line 28.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen141
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count196
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count197
\leftroot@=\count198
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 410.
\classnum@=\count199
\DOTSCASE@=\count266
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box66
\strutbox@=\box67
LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 722.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 724.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 725.
\big@size=\dimen142
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count267
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 905.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 910.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 940.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 970.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 971.
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count268
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count269
\dspbrk@lvl=\count270
\tag@help=\toks21
\row@=\count271
\column@=\count272
\maxfields@=\count273
\andhelp@=\toks22
\eqnshift@=\dimen143
\alignsep@=\dimen144
\tagshift@=\dimen145
\tagwidth@=\dimen146
\totwidth@=\dimen147
\lineht@=\dimen148
\@envbody=\toks23
\multlinegap=\skip52
\multlinetaggap=\skip53
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks24
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2953.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip17
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip54
\bibsep=\skip55
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count274
)
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing natbib's \BibitemShut on input line 7676.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/revsymb4-2.sty
Package: revsymb4-2 2022/06/05 4.2f (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for documentation)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frak on input line 104.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bbb on input line 120.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \REV@mathfrak on input line 128.
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks25
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 107.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2022/09/22 v5.0n Graphics/color driver for xetex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen149
\Gin@req@width=\dimen150
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/dcolumn.sty
Package: dcolumn 2014/10/28 v1.06 decimal alignment package (DPC)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2022/09/04 v2.5g Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen151
\ar@mcellbox=\box68
\extrarowheight=\dimen152
\NC@list=\toks26
\extratabsurround=\skip56
\backup@length=\skip57
\ar@cellbox=\box69
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/bm.sty
Package: bm 2022/01/05 v1.2f Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
\symboldoperators=\mathgroup6
\symboldletters=\mathgroup7
\symboldsymbols=\mathgroup8
Package bm Info: No bold for \OMX/cmex/m/n, using \pmb.
Package bm Info: No bold for \U/msa/m/n, using \pmb.
Package bm Info: No bold for \U/msb/m/n, using \pmb.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 149.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bm on input line 219.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count275
\float@exts=\toks27
\float@box=\box70
\@float@everytoks=\toks28
\@floatcapt=\box71
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xr.sty
Package: xr 2020-05-10 v5.06 eXternal References (DPC)
)
Package xr Info: IMPORTING LABELS FROM MAIN.aux on input line 26.
Class revtex4-2 Info: Unrecognized array package. Please update this document class! (Proceeding with fingers crossed.) on input line 28.

Class revtex4-2 Warning: Repair the float package.

Class revtex4-2 Info: cite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 28.
Class revtex4-2 Info: mcite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 28.
Class revtex4-2 Info: multicol was not loaded (OK!) on input line 28.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2023-04-19 L3 backend support: XeTeX
\g__graphics_track_int=\count276
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box72
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count277
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count278
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count279
) (./output.aux)
\openout1 = `output.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 28.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 28.
\openout3 = `outputNotes.bib'.

Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 31 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 31 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 31 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 31 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 31 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 31 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 31 replaced by U+FFFD.
File: SI figures/Final SI Figures/SI 7 - Lengths.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<SI figures/Final SI Figures/SI 7 - Lengths.eps>

LaTeX Warning: Reference `DefineWiggle' on page 1 undefined on input line 32.

(./output.bbl) [1] (./output.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-06-30>
 ***********

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 4438 strings out of 475890
 62969 string characters out of 5778498
 1909875 words of memory out of 5000000
 25465 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558093 words of font info for 39 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 71i,5n,79p,226b,396s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

Output written on output.xdv (1 page, 1584 bytes).

Thank you again!

Welcome! Can you provide us with code for two small but complete documents which we can compile to reproduce the problem you're having?

you need to show a small example and show the log you get. for code and the log use a code block ({}  button in the editor or three \``` before and after the code)

you can't have cyclic references using xr, you can reference another document, but not the other way. also you should only refernce the other document once, one of these two must be wrong\externaldocument{SuppInfo} \externaldocument{output-subdoc/SuppInfo}

Welcome. // Ok, you made some syntactically changes to your post, but that’s not what’s needed. Because LaTeX is complex you need to prepare a short example that a) compiles and b) still shows your problem. // To illustrate by an analogy at the moment it’s like you cited „So be it“ from a novel and leave it to us to guess title, author and genre. Perhaps it isn’t a novel at all? This makes helping you next to impossible . // Thank you

thank you, all!  i edited my post as requested to include two small files and their logs.  these files contain one labeled element each, and each references the labeled element in the other.  they compile into pdfs, and the log file for each even says the labels have been imported from the other, but still the pdf shows "??" in pace of the proper cross reference.

...also, @DavidCarlisle says xr doesn't allow cyclic references -- is there another package that would allow that?

note \includegraphics{SI figures/Final SI Figures/SI 7 - Lengths.eps} just makes it harder for anyone to run the example and no image is needed to demonstrate cross references

@DavidCarlisle interesting! when i comment out the "\includegraphics" command, the cross references compile..!  but now i have no figures, so that's not a viable solution...

@user219579 no that is not happening, \includegraphics has absolutely no effect on xr references. i commented it out iin my answer and suggested you remove  it from the question simply as no one but you has that image file so the posted example gives missing file errors for everyone but you

@DavidCarlisle, so, i am working online in overleaf.  here is what just happened: i comment out \includegraphics in both files and they compile and references appear in both, properly.  i uncomment \includgraphics in both files and the ?? reappear.  so, my experience suggests there is something about \includegraphics that is interfering.  what else could be happening to explain compiling fine without \includegraphics but ?? appearing with \includegraphics?  any other suggestions?  thank you!

do you get an error on the graphics that stops the run? (if you get any error at all, ignore the output) but I wrote all the packages you use, graphicx, bm, dcolumn, xr (and parts of revtex) I do have an idea bout which packages affect which commands. If it would make you happier I could put the \includegraphics back in my answer, using example-image which is a generally available test image.

hm, no, there is no error on the graphics that stops the run...  thank you for the offer -- can you indeed try the \includegraphics with an example-image and see what happens on your end?

@smh I just updated my answer with Overleaf notes and your example running on overleaf

@DavidCarlisle thank you very much for all your help!  the overleaf project that you shared works on my browser.  this is great.  *my project still doesn't work in my browser, even with adding the hooks at the end of the tex files. but it looks like my project has a different settings environment than the project link from you.  so i will simply copy that project and then add my content in there.  thank you again!

note you need to process each document in order at least twice before the references resolve

See Below for Overleaf Notes

If you cyclic link with no prefix you will get multiply defined labels including automatically added labels, specifically in this example
LaTeX Warning: Label `LastPage' multiply defined.


However if you prefix the references, it all works: the cyclic reference is not a problem (clearly the package is written by a brilliant author, it worked better than I expected:-)
MAIN.pdf

SuppInfo.pdf

from running
xelatex MAIN
xelatex SuppInfo
xelatex MAIN
xelatex SuppInfo

(in that order)
on
MAIN.tex
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,prl,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xr}
\makeatletter

%begin helper code
\newcommand*{\addFileDependency}[1]{% argument=file name and extension
\typeout{(#1)}
\@addtofilelist{#1}
\IfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}
}\makeatother
\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[1]{%
\externaldocument{#1}%
\addFileDependency{#1.tex}%
\addFileDependency{#1.aux}%
} %end helper code
\externaldocument[supp-]{SuppInfo}

\begin{document}

\preprint{APS/123-QED}


\begin{figure*}
GGGGGGG%\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/Figure 3.eps}
\caption{\label{DefineWiggle} (a) shows the definition. The full distribution is shown in Figure \ref{supp-SI-lengths}.}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}

SuppInfo.tex
\documentclass[
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{xr}
\makeatletter

%begin helper code
\newcommand*{\addFileDependency}[1]{% argument=file name and extension
\typeout{(#1)}
\@addtofilelist{#1}
\IfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}
}\makeatother
\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[1]{%
\externaldocument{#1}%
\addFileDependency{#1.tex}%
\addFileDependency{#1.aux}%
} %end helper code

\externaldocument[main-]{MAIN}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
GGGGGGG%\includegraphics{SI figures/Final SI Figures/SI 7 - Lengths.eps}
\caption{\label{SI-lengths} Histogram obtained by the method described in Figure \ref{main-DefineWiggle}.}
\end{figure}
  
\end{document}


OverLeaf
On overleaf you have an additional problem that all documents set the \jobname to output so the aux files overwrite each other. You could use some perl in latexmkrc but simpler is to save them just using the direct shell escape, it needs to be in a hook to savethe aux file after it has been finalised.
end SuppInfo with

\AddToHook{enddocument/afteraux}{%
\immediate\write18{
cp output.aux SuppInfo.aux
}%
}
\end{document}

and MAIN with

\AddToHook{enddocument/afteraux}{%
\immediate\write18{
cp output.aux MAIN.aux
}%
}
\end{document}

Then the aux files havethe "expected" names and xr will find them.
For now at least a world readable Overleaf project  showing this is available here
https://www.overleaf.com/read/tpyjbswzqspp#38f94b
which makes

